# Finding Range of active/selected cell in Excel using Python and xlwings - continued

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, xlwings

I'm coming from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901092/finding-range-of-active-selected-cell-in-excel-using-python-and-xlwings)

This isn't working for me. I'm using xlwings in Jupyter Lab.

```
import xlwings as xw
app = xw.App
r = app.selection
print r
```

works just fine it returns: property at 0x8919598>

but trying to access any property of the range fails. r.row returns: 'property' object has no attribute 'row' same for "address", "column", "value"

I tried combinations of parenthesis and api: r.api.row, r.api.row(), r.row() ... no success.

I looked at available commands by pressing tab shift and got (.deleter, .fedel, .fget. .fset, .getter, .setter). So I tried to extract the desired property r.fget("address") --> no success.

xlwings's version is 0.11.7 excel's version is 13 windows 7

Could anyone give some hint where to look next? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I see correctly you didn't instantiate the `App`.

```
import xlwings as xw
app = xw.App()
r = app.selection
print r
```

Comment: How crazy is that? Thank you soooo much. The problem is that the assignement seemed to work just fine. There was no indication so far, that it failed. Been banging my head for more than 1 week on this silly bug. You deserve the points. Thanks.

Comment: @y4cine if that solved your problem please accept this answer

Comment: @KamilNiski When i run your code it opens a new instance of excel instead of returning the selected range of an open workbook.

Comment: @rohrl77 if you have a question please create a new one. Meanwhile refer to the docs https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: @KamilNiski Merely pointing out that if this is the answer, it doesn't work consistently

Comment: @rohrl77, haven't yet worked out how to get the app from the active sheet, but if you open an existing workbook the following should work: wb = xw.Book(yourFILENAME) / app = wb.app. Now app is instantiated and app.selection returns the desired range instead of a property. At least in this scenario, you won't create a new empty wb. Next step will be to find out how to get the selection of the active app/wb/sht.

Answer (score 1):

Working off of Kamil's answer I managed to get the reference to the currently active workbook, with the active and selected range. I believe this answers the OP's original question.

```
import xlwings as xw
xlapp = xw.apps.active
rng = xlapp.selection
print (rng.address)
```

Comment: I'd split the bounty between you and Kamil if I could ;). Despite, it was finding the bug that mattered the most. Cheers and thanks.

Comment: no worries. i think Kamil deserves the bounty. thanks!